# Bootstrap Mega Menu Module - clicking a menu item does not show sub menu items

Tags: module, menu-item, menu, submenu

I am using Bootstrap Mega Menu Module to create multicolumn sub menus under main menu. My menu tree is like:

```
Home (Single article, default)
Fields of Study (Article Category List: show articles in a category named FoS)
- History (Single article: under FoS)
- Literature (Single article FoS)
- Social researches (Single article FoS)
...
```

If I use Joomla's built-in menu module, I can see sub menu items when I click on "Fields of Study" item. There is no postback.

But

If I use [Bootstrap Mega Menu Module](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/t-bootstrap-mega-menu), the page opens the category list page when I click on "Fields of Study" item. eventhough I can see the submenu opens, I cannot click on the items in it, because the page reloads.

Comment: What Joomla version? Have you tried different templates?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like it could be a known conflict between jQuery and Mootools. Solution, disable mootools. I'd suggest @phproberto's excellent Mootable plugin as it will allow you to cleanly and completely remove Mootools with a high degree of control: https://github.com/phproberto/plg_sys_mootable